# How to run a worker or workers on Heroku undefinitely and how do they differ from `web`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, heroku, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'd like to have two separate instances of PhantomJS constantly waiting on an "Ask" from the main application.

I'm confused how a `worker` difference from a `web` process on heroku.

In the Procfile, if I were to define `web` as NOT my application and started it from the `worker` process, what would happen?
Or, for example, puma web server starts out multiple threads. Does the web `process` acount for multiple threads or do you need a web or worker per every thread puma creates?

Thanks

Comment: In essence, everything that is not web, does not get any http requests. The rest is the same. Processes start and do whatever they are supposed to do.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Does a process imply it has to be just one thread or not necessarily?

Comment: Nope, it can be many threads. A puma process with all its threads is one dyno.